# Automatically upload binary file to nucleo after compiling in Keil

Tags: keil, nucleo

I bought Nucleo F411RE and I'm using Keil uVision 5 as IDE for programming it. To download program to Nucleo, you simply copy it in the virtual nucleo drive:

[image: uploading binary file to nucleo]

Of course, I'd like to have this task automated. To do so, I tried to use the Keil project configuration:

[image: keil run after compilation]

But that doesn't work:

```
*** Error: CreateProcess failed, Command: 'copy build\Nucleo_blink_led_NUCLEO_F411RE.bin H:\'
```

So what should I do? Keil is recommended by Nucleo manufacturer, yet this simple issue seems to have no solution on the internet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why this didn't work, but `xcopy` command works well:

[image: copy file nucleo keil]

Comment: Probably works because there is an xcopy.exe program, whereas copy is handled internally by cmd.exe